# C rand() is not really random

Tags: c++, c, random

I'm working on an application.
I'm using:

```
int rand_num = rand() % 100;
```

To get a random integer between 0 to 99.
Now, let's say I got 41, then restarting my application, it's always 41. Same sequence over and over, means it's not really random.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand` generates a pseudo-random number, yes. But you can set the seed.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int rand_num = rand() % 100;
```

Set the seed only once.

Or you can use one of the methods from [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Answer (score 7):

You have to randomize the seed by calling [`srand(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) (usually with `time(0)`) whenever you start your application. Note that it is a pseudo-random number generator i.e. the values generated by the `rand()` function are not uniformly distributed.

Comment: I don't really understand... Is there a chance to get a snipper, some function like random(min, max);? I'd be greatful!

Comment: @Ariel given an interval, you can generate a pseudo-random number by doing `rand() % (max-min)` and incrementing it by `min`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
#include<time.h>

srand(time(NULL));
```

It will change the seed of pseudo-random generator.

For more information see [this](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-srand-initialize-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 3):

Correct. rand() returns a pseudo-random number. The sequence from a given start is deterministic. You can alter the starting point using srand().